# How can I prevent a textbox's content from being edited NOT on IE, with xml on C# asp.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, contenteditable

I was having some serious issues with a textbox that I have on a page that's used with a calendar extender, looks like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="fnTB" runat="server" ReadOnly="True"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox1_CalendarExtender" runat="server" 
                    Enabled="True" TargetControlID="fnTB" DefaultView="Years"></asp:CalendarExtender>
```

Now, the issues were caused by the "ReadOnly" attribute. Since my business logic makes some validations with the date, it is very strict with the date's format, so I made the textbox readonly to prevent users from messing up the date's format. The problem is that now with this property set to `true` the `textbox.Text` property is set to `""` all the time.

From what I found out on microsoft's forums about this property, it says that

> the server does no processing for a read-only text box. This prevents a malicious user from changing a Text value that is read-only. The value of the Text property is preserved in the view state between postbacks unless modified by server-side code

and then they suggest to use the `contentEditable` property instead. Problem is that this property works only on IE browser, which is not what we need cause users must be able to access the site from any browser.

So I was wondering if there was a way to do this without using this property.

Thanks in advance for your kind help!

Answer (score 2):

If you truly want a readonly field to expose data via binding, I'd recommend using Label if you need it to describe or represent another control.

```
<asp:Label ID="fnTB" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Alternatively, if you simply need to show uneditable text, you can use a span with a literal.

```
<span class="foo"><asp:Literal id="fnTB" runa="server" /></span>
```

Comment: No, it's not from data binding, it's a calendar. There is another control right under the TextBox that is a CalendarExtender; I need users to USE that textbox to input dates, but I need them to use the calendar extender ONLY, not to input the date as text manually.

Comment: If I understand you however, you are not using the TextBox for input correct?  You are using the calendar extender, which is then shown correctly formatted in the text box.

Comment: The calendar extender provides a graphic interface to browse through the months, and when you select a date the extender writes the date into the TargetControlID control, which is the textbox in my case.

Comment: If that's the case, I think my solutions will both work for you.  Unless there is something in the calendar extender that explicitly requires it to be a text box, it should locate it by Id.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is to not make this field readonly, but rather to permit it to be edited and add appropriate validation to ensure that it is in the correct format.

To expand a little, setting a UI control to readonly, or disabled will still not stop someone who is determined (*cough* firebug *cough*) from changing the content.  And you run into the problems you mentioned above.

Input should **always** be validated, no exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You can add in the OnTextChanged event.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="fnTB" runat="server" OnTextChanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

When you plan on setting the value you can disable the event. In the event handler you can ignore any changes so that the textbox is essentially read only.

```
protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   e.Handled = true;    // Ignore any input.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is `Enabled='false'`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="fnTB" runat="server" Enabled="false" />
```

This will render the control in such a way:

```
<input name="fnTB" type="text" id="fnTB" disabled="disabled" class="aspNetDisabled">
```

You'll still be able to assign a value to it and retrieve a value on postback but the user will not be able to type into this field. But of course you still need to consider the security implications of this (ie it's value is easily change via the likes of inspector/firebug).